# Any advice to use mobx with i18n (internationalization) in my React JS app

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

in my Mobx + React JS application, I use the internationalization behavior.
See the following example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  InjectedTranslateProps,
  translate
} from 'react-i18next'

import {
  IPropsBase,
  IStateBase
} from './interfaces'

class HomeClass extends Component<IPropsBase & InjectedTranslateProps, IStateBase> {
  render () {
    const { t } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {t('common:WELCOME')}
        {t('common:DESCRIPTION')}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const Home = translate()(HomeClass)
```

I want to know if you have any other way to do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want to do different?

Comment: Hi jamuhl, the main idea is to use internationalization feature in my site (change the texts from "en" to "fr"). But the 'observer' of MobX only listen any change for an 'observable' value and not for label (not observable). For example, the placeholder attribute in a html input field does not change its text, its only change when I update the input value property. So, I feel that MobX blocks the render process of my internationalization process. I use react-intl-universal for my internationalization feature. Thanks in advance for any idea.

Comment: the translate hoc triggers a rerender by passing down updated props to you component -> so it should rerender on i18next.changeLanguage. Won't happen in react-intl-universal as there is no real solution for language changing beside adding manually more translations and rerender the full app i guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use Provider or HOCs and you don't need to set certain namespaces for each component, you can use mobx observable for rendering language toggle.

Just create observable object in which your function **t** will be stored and **changeLanguage** function wrapper in which **t** function will be reassigned.

As mobx reacts to any observable change that used in render method, this will trigger rerender in all components that use **t** function.

```
export let i18n = observable({
    t: t
});

export function changeLanguage (lg: string) {
    i18next.changeLanguage(lg);
    this.i18n.t = i18next.getFixedT(lg, i18nCfg.ns);// getFixedT will return new function t
}
```